# Instergrate Google Translate Eclipse plugin to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, translate

I try to use Google Translate in eclipse.

> https://code.google.com/p/google-translate-eclipse-plugin/

But i don't know how to install Google Translate Eclipse plugin to eclipse.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

It's old, abandoned and doesn't actually work in any recent Eclipse. Some people have [adopted the code into their own GitHub accounts](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=google-translate-eclipse-plugin), but I haven't seen anyone actually get it working. And most of the GitHub cuts have few or no edits. I think we all imported it hoping it was in better shape than it was.

I took a quick look at it, but it might just be a completely invalid plugin now. It is unclear if it ever worked.

I'll continue to work on it in my spare time, as I really need something like this, but I make no promises.

[Later]

As promised, I took a look at the code, and it is essentially unsalvageable. It would be better to start from scratch. It uses only deprecated Extensions, and relies on pretty brittle substring match screen-scraping that doesn't work anymore, and is nearly impossible to fix.

It's on my list of utils to write, but I'm not actively working on it.